# How to set the x and y Scale of a matplotlib Plot in a tkinter canvas

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg,   NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure



class tkPlot:
    def __init__(self,master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack()

        canvasSubFrame=Frame(frame)
        canvasSubFrame.grid(row=0, column=0)

        f = Figure(figsize=(8,8), dpi=100)
        subplotA = f.add_subplot(211)
        subplotA.set_title("Plot A")
        subplotB = f.add_subplot(212)
        subplotB.set_title("Plot B")

        subplotA.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,4,9,16,25,36])
        subplotB.plot([1,2,3,4,5,6],[1,1/2,1/3,1/4,1/5,1/6])

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=canvasSubFrame)
        canvas.draw()
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(expand=False)      

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = tkPlot(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Ideally, i would like to have a textbox or spin control besides every top and bottom of each subplot to set the y axes min and max scales (y limits)

What is the proper way to do this. It should work for any number of subplots.

Comment: Is the question how to get the coordinates of the subplots in order to be able to position the Spin boxes to those coordinates?

Comment: I want to position the spin boxes and the canvas in a grid layout if possible. Don't know if the pixel values of the subplots are by itself of any use.

Comment: Ah, so the SpinBoxes will be next to the canvas, not on top of it. This seems much easier. Did you try it? What's the outcome?